# Conflicting Public IP Addresses

Tags: networking, ip

I'm stumped.  ipchicken.com is saying our ip address is 172.68.34.125.  All other services (google, whatsmyip.org, etc) are saying our public ip address is 64.207.55.1.   It should be 64.207.55.1 because that is what our gateway ip address is.  I'm worried because ipchicken.com is usually the credible one.

My friends at our service provided don't have an answer for me. I'm wondering if our network's been hacked.

Answer (score 1):

[172.68.34.125](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/172.68.34.125) is a CloudFlare IP address. [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/overview/) is a service that website owners use for DNS, CDN and security purposes, which performs routing and redirection to sites. As such it is quite likely that when cloudflare is in play, the IP pathway to reach the site varies based on their routing decisions.

Generally, to configure your site to use CloudFlare, you need only repoint your DNS domain configuration so that queries to your site are resolved through the cloudflare network.

In this case, IPChicken.com is seeing the 172.68 address because its on the other side of the Internet, and is routed through cloudflare on its way to you, but when you test it from a point within the affected network, it correctly resolves as the non-cloudflare ISP-allocated IP address.

Comment: Thank you Frank.  However, I'm not using CloudFlare services and my isp says they do not use the service either.

Comment: could ipchicken be using it? could they have started using it and not implemented the forwarded for properly? that's what it sounds like to me. Your server using cloudflare should impact your server talking to another service, it's usually the opposite that goes through cloudflare.

Comment: @KevinB, that is a very reasonable conjecture, It is absolutely clear that Cloudflare is at play in the process.

Comment: [agreed](https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-172-64-0-0-1/pft?s=172.68.34.125) and the other address [reports as Cbeyond Communications](https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-64-207-0-0-1/pft?s=64.207.55.1)